# How to move BigQuery database from uswest2 to uswest1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

[image]

We are looking to move our BigQuery database (with 7 datasets) from uswest2 to uswest1. We are attempting to copy a BigQuery dataset, and notice the following infomodal that says we cannot copy cross region...

What is the best way / best practice to move a BigQuery database across regions where cross-region copying is not supported?

Comment: i think, `uswest2 to uswest1` should actually work - have you tried? - or you were blocked by above infomodal?

Comment: Ahh I see now, yes you are correct. I need to select CREATE NEW DATASET, rather than typing in the exact dataset name I am moving

Answer (score 1):

Posting it as wikianswer for the benefit of the community. As stated by @Canovice in the comment section, to copy the dataset user need to select `CREATE NEW DATASET` in the `DATASET` field. To know more about copying a dataset you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#setting_up_a_dataset_copy).